# Expo React Native Debugger error: Could not read source map for webpack://ReactDevToolsBackend/../../src/index.ts: Invalid URL

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, native, visual-studio-debugging

When I launch the expo debugger in VScode I get this error: Could not read source map for webpack://ReactDevToolsBackend/../../src/index.ts: Invalid URL. Then when I try to run anything in the console it crashes the simulator.

I expected the simulator to just run.